# Can I use "it's" with a plural noun?

Tags: word-choice, pronouns, singular-vs-plural

Can I use "it's" with a plural noun?

> We have many disasters in our country. In the summer, **it's fires** and in the autumn **it's floods**.

Comment: In general, yes. E.g.: “What’s the source of that smoke?” “It’s the fires in the valley.” However, I agree with Chasly that in your sentence “it” doesn't agree with its apparent referent.

Answer (score 3):

**Not really**

It's understandable but very informal. You are not referring back to the plural noun with this construction. Instead there is an implied referent for "it" that the listener has to supply mentally.

For any written communication that is even slightly formal, I wouldn't use this.

---

Here is one possible rephrase.

We have many disasters in our country. In the summer there are fires and in the autumn, floods

Comment: I don't find anything wrong with the OP's form